# Python selenium click at coordinates of img

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing script to by-bass captcha like the image below

[image]

The api to resolve captcha return like this

```
{
 'captchaId': '73829948390', 
 'code': 'coordinates:x=142,y=37'
}
```

How can I click at the position which is returned by the api using selenium and python?

I have tried with the code below:

```
        element = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#captcha")
        txtSpilit = re.split("coordinates\:x=(\d*),y=(\d*)", txt)
        x = txtSpilit[1]
        y = txtSpilit[2]
        loc = element.location
        X, Y = int(loc.get('x')), int(loc.get('y'))
        pyautogui.moveTo(int(x) + X, int(y) + Y, duration=0.5)
        pyautogui.click(int(x) + X, int(y) + Y)
```